# Convert eps figures into a single pdf file

Tags: pdf, epstopdf, auto-pst-pdf

I have many eps figures in my latex file. Conventionally, after compiling, there will be one pdf file for each eps figure. So in my case, there are tons of these pdf files.

My goal is, instead of one pdf for each eps, combine all of eps figure them into ONE pdf file. I can do this by invoking `auto-pst-pdf` package. But this requires shell escape and seems not quite universal (e.g., I can't do this in VScode).

So I am wondering is there anyway that I can have single pdf file containing all eps, instead of tons of them?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: You can do it in the shell with epstopdf and pdfjam or pdftk.

Comment: @EuklidAlexandria Could you be a little bit more specific?

Comment: Suppose you have a `fig.eps` file. Convert manually: open console, change to the directory containing eps file, execute `epstopdf fig.eps`. This converts `fig.eps` to `fig.pdf`. Convert automatically: create a tex file containing `\includegraphics{fig}`, run `pdflatex` to compile the tex file. This converts `fig.eps` to `fig-eps-converted-to.pdf`. Both methods uses `epstopdf`, which is provided by software GhostScript.

Comment: you could make a single pdf file but then it is more complicated (and slower) to include the separate parts of that file back into your latex document as separate images.  Are you sure that you want to do that?

Comment: the generated pdf files are just internal workings of the pdflatex run like aux file or bbl file, why do you mind if they are generated?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Because I got tons of eps figures in my file. If pdf files is generated for every one of them, it becomes really cumbersome. Maybe I can switch to `Latex->dvips->ps2pdf` instead of using `pdflatex`?

Comment: @SJH I have added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following shell script converts all eps-files inside the same directory to pdf-files and joins them.

```
#!/bin/sh

eps2pdf() {
    for f in *.eps
    do
       epstopdf "$f"
       echo "$(basename "$f" .eps).pdf"
    done
}

pdfjoin $(eps2pdf) --outfile joined.pdf
```